# How to force every line to have the same # of tabs as the maximum length line

Tags: python, csv

I have a tab-delimited txt, and I want to make every row has the same number of tabs as the row with the largest number of tabs.

For example,

```
A\tB\tC\tD
E\t
F\tG\t
```

input file : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1sEqo7wNB1-bmpKaWdrSmUtcUE/edit?usp=sharing
will become

```
A\tB\tC\tD
E\t\t\t
F\tG\t\t
```

I am trying this.

```
import sys
from itertools import izip_longest
import codecs

inputf  = sys.argv[1]
outputf  = sys.argv[2]

with open(inputf) as f:
    data = izip_longest(*(x.split('\t') for x in f), fillvalue='\t')
for line in zip(*data):
    print line,

ofile = codecs.open(outputf, "w")
```

But output has nothing although it prints things in command window.

I hope this program doesn't prints these in command window (it seems it takes much time)

and I hope the output file has the correct output.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use csv module, like this

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import csv
from itertools import izip_longest

def read_rows(inputfile):
    with open(inputfile, 'rb') as h:
        reader = csv.reader(h, dialect='excel-tab')
        return list(reader)

def write_rows(outputfile, rows):
    with open(outputfile, 'wb') as h:
        writer = csv.writer(h, dialect='excel-tab')
        for row in rows:
            writer.writerow(row)

def show_file(outputfile):
    with open(outputfile, 'r') as h:
        print h.read().splitlines()

def main(inputfile, outputfile):
    rows = read_rows(inputfile)
    rows = zip(*(izip_longest(*rows, fillvalue='')))
    write_rows(outputfile, rows)
    show_file(outputfile)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    inputfile = sys.argv[1]
    outputfile = sys.argv[2]
    main(inputfile, outputfile)
```

With your input file:

```
./normalize.py ~/Downloads/input.txt ~/Downloads/output.txt 
['A\tB\tC\tD', 'E\t\t\t', 'F\tG\t\t']
```

Comment: In the `write_rows()` function you could just use a single `writer.writerows(rows)` call instead of the `for` loop. Also the `show_file()` function probably isn't needed since the OP complained about the printing of the output to the command window was taking too much time.

Answer (score 1):

You're seeing the output in the command window because you're printing out what's in`data`(which consumes the iterator returned by`izip_longest()`). Nothing ends up in the file because no data is ever written to it, you only opened it for writing.

I believe the following will do (only) what you want:

```
import sys
from itertools import izip_longest
import codecs

inputf = sys.argv[1]
outputf = sys.argv[2]

with open(inputf) as f:
    data = izip_longest(*(x.strip().split('\t') for x in f), fillvalue='')

with codecs.open(outputf, "w") as ofile:
    ofile.write('\n'.join('\t'.join(items) for items in zip(*data)) + '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
But output has nothing although it prints things in command window.
```

This is because you are not writing the data to the file.

Change your program as follows

```
with open(inputf) as fin, open(outputf, "w") as fout:
    data = izip_longest(*(x.split('\t') for x in fin), fillvalue='\t')
    fout.write('\n'.join(map(''.join, zip(*data))))
```

Note, your program may not give the desired output as the newline character is part of the characters in the list of elements you are zipping. You need to strip off the newline from the lines read

```
    data = izip_longest(*(x.strip().split('\t') for x in f), fillvalue='\t')
```

Comment: Perhaps the second inputf should be outputf ?

Comment: I tested your original code, then it says "name f is not defined". So I replaced "x in f" with "x in fin" but this didn't provide any output, and then changed the second inputf to outputf, and same problem happens.

Comment: This is input file https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1sEqo7wNB1-bmpKaWdrSmUtcUE/edit?usp=sharing